# Markup() function returns markup outside of tags with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, markup, jinja2

Before I tell you my issue, I think it would be easier to show you my code.

**HTML with Jinja**

```
<p>{{ item }}</p>
```

**'Flask**

```
item = Markup('<ul><li>list item 1</li><li>list item 2</li></ul>')
```

My issue is, when the HTML page is loaded, the markup looks like this:

**HTML when Page Loaded**

```
<p></p>
<ul>
<li>list item 1</li>
<li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
```

So as you can see, the contents of 'item' are not inside the paragraph tags as I specified in the HTML with Jinja. I've tried some workarounds but they are not any good. There is nothing else I can say other then I have no clue on how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't confuse the *DOM tree* with the *HTML source* produced by Jinja2 here. Your browser *transforms* HTML into an object tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<p>` elements can't contain `<ul>` elements, so the browser places the list after the paragraph. If you need them to nest, replace `<p>` with `<div>`.